# HTML Encode / Decode : Perl / Python output does not match

Tags: python, perl, unicode, utf-8

Input Text: ABC™ Blue<sup>®</sup> Testmix, 200 x 20 µl rxns, 2 ml (2 x 1 ml)

Using this online tool to verify the output for encode and decode:
http://www.web2generators.com/html-based-tools/online-html-entities-encoder-and-decoder, the output returned by the website are below:

```
Decode Text 
ABC™ Blue<sup>®</sup> Testmix, 200 x 20 µl rxns, 2 ml (2 x 1 ml)

Encode Text
ABC&trade; Blue&lt;sup&gt;&reg;&lt;/sup&gt; Testmix, 200 x 20 &micro;l rxns, 2 ml (2 x 1 ml)
```

I wrote Perl and Python code to try to see if I can get the same output:

Python Code

```
from HTMLParser import HTMLParser
try:
    from html import escape  # python 3.x
except ImportError:
    from cgi import escape  # python 2.x


def htmldecode(s):
        h = HTMLParser()
        return h.unescape(s)

text = "ABC™ Blue<sup>®</sup> Testmix, 200 x 20 µl rxns, 2 ml (2 x 1 ml)"
print (htmldecode(text))
print (escape(htmldecode(text)))
```

Output from Python for Encode Text :

```
ABC™ Blue&lt;sup&gt;®&lt;/sup&gt; Testmix, 200 x 20 µl rxns, 2 ml (2 x 1 ml)
```

Tried Perl Code as well

```
use HTML::Entities;

my $input = "ABC™ Blue<sup>®</sup> Testmix, 200 x 20 µl rxns, 2 ml (2 x 1 ml)";
print encode_entities($input), "\n"
```

However, the output is

```
ABC&acirc;&#132;&cent; Blue&lt;sup&gt;&Acirc;&reg;&lt;/sup&gt; Testmix, 200 x 20 &Acirc;&micro;l rxns, 2 ml (2 x 1 ml)
```

What am i doing wrong that the output does not match the output returned from http://www.web2generators.com/html-based-tools/online-html-entities-encoder-and-decoder

Answer (score 2):

You haven't told Perl your script is saved in UTF-8. Just add

```
use utf8;
```

somewhere near the beginning of the script (best place is right after `use strict;` and `use warnings;`).

See [utf8](http://p3rl.org/utf8).

Comment: Sorry .. i got happy a bit too soon. I tried to pass the input text as a parameter and the problem is back ! I tied to add #use open qw(:std :utf8); to the script.. but it does not work either.

Comment: Managed to get it to run by passing the following command line flags while running by code: perl -Mutf8 -CA  . Thanks!